# Can heavy MySQL load cause PostgreSQL connection problems?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I am running PHP, PostgreSQL, and MySQL. Once a day, at the same time each day, I see the below error when PHP tries to connect to PostgreSQL:

> pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Resource temporarily unavailable Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

At this point, PostgreSQL is barely loaded in terms of connections, from what I can see.

However, MySQL is unusually heavily loaded in terms of connections at exactly the same point in time.

Is it possible that the MySQL connection load is causing the issue in connecting to PostgreSQL?

Comment: A system resource is exhausted. Perhaps the number of processes per user?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for many scenarios, but you need to check something in your server, for example, if you have older versions of PostgreSQL in your OS removed all of them, also can be a configuration in your OS you need to make sure the limits in the processes and in the socket traffic. Check the answers in this link, there are some that can help you to identify the issue in your processes:

[Access Postgres when I get an error about "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182189/how-do-i-access-postgres-when-i-get-an-error-about-var-run-postgresql-s-pgsql)